# Dynamically change/update step title in "jQuery steps" without "delete"+"add"?

Tags: jquery

How can I dynamically change/update a title in "jQuery steps" without "delete" and "add" a step?

---

Wow, downvoters, if you want to see code, see my answer. This question makes totally sense to me and I think for other Googlers too.

Comment: One sentence rarely makes for a good question. Please explain what you're question/issue is and demonstrate with code what you've tried.

Comment: `html()`,`text()`, without some sort of context it would be impossible to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out myself, see in `onStepChanged:`

```
$("#wizard").steps({
    autoFocus: true,
    bodyTag: "section",
    headerTag: "h6",
    labels:
    {
        current: "current step:",
        pagination: "Pagination",
        finish: "Ende",
        next: "Vor",
        previous: "Zurueck",
        loading: "Lade es..."
    },
    onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
    {

    },
    onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, priorIndex)
    {
        obj = $("#wizard-t-" + currentIndex);
        title_ = "ABC";
        html_zaehler = obj.html()
        html_zaehler = html_zaehler.split(".</span>")[0] + ".</span>";
        obj.html(html_zaehler + " " + title_);
    },
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft"
});
```